# Unable to load data into mysql from .sql file in hortonworks hadoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs

I am working on hadoop and facing one issue. i have uploaded file in hadoop files view which is .sql file. and im validating its here in hadoop at `mysqluploads/sqoop-data-setup.sql`

I have tested it, by command

```
hadoop fs -ls /mysqluploads/sqoop-data-setup.sql hadoop fs -cat /mysqluploads/sqoop-data-setup.sql
```

now issue is, i want to import this data into mysql database; I am typing after logon in mysql source `/mysqluploads/sqoop-data-setup.sql`

It is showing me the following error

> ERROR: Failed to open file 'root\mysqluploads\sqoop-data-setup.sql', error: 2

Comment: linux file permissions wrong ? Wrong file path ?

Comment: Also the error file path does not match anny off the used command file paths?